# Windows server does not serve .plist and .ipa files

Tags: windows-server-2008

`.plist` and `.ipa` are files for iOS enterprise distribution of Apps.

I want to host them on my enterprise server for distribution. However, the server used does not allow these kinds of files.

I have uploaded them to the directory, when I try to download them I get the following error:

[image]

If I only change the extension to "txt", "rar" or any popular extensions. The file gets downloaded with no errors.

What is the problem? Is it a security measure for Windows server or just a blacklist/whitelist of files?

How to solve it.

Windows Server 2008

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to [add a MIME type mapping](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725608(v=ws.10).aspx) for the `.ipa` and `.plist` extensions:

```
appcmd set config "Website name" /section:staticContent /+"[fileExtension='.plist',mimeType=' application/xml']"
appcmd set config "Website name" /section:staticContent /+"[fileExtension='.ipa',mimeType=' application/octet-stream']"
```

`appcmd.exe` is located in `%windir%\System32\inetsrv\`